# Ruby StringIO Error _dump_data - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, evernote

I have a strange issue I cannot solve. I am using oAuth and the Evernote API in a Rails app.
I have 2 controllers I am using for this atm.

CallbacksController
http://paste.codebasehq.com/pastes/sazk9j2lmnjfqvtio4

BoardsController
http://paste.codebasehq.com/pastes/yx2ymolh15wz3v0ctg

The connection works fine and I am able to get a list of my NoteBooks in the controller and view the data using `raise`. When I comment out raise I get this error:

```
no _dump_data is defined for class StringIO
```

`@notebooks` is an Array and this is the output from `raise`

```
["theonramp's notebook", "another notebook"]
```

Looks fine to me, so I am at a loss. I have searched high and low for this error, but have found nothing. That's all the error says, fairly unhelpful.

Anyone else run across this error.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Rails didn't like NoteStore saved in the session. I moved it out and called it with a before_filter and all is well.